# Unauthorized error while login using vcloud sdk

Tags: vmware

i am using vcloud air SDK for creating vapp in vmware.i want to create vapp using java for that i am usig composeAPP API.
 i am getting below error while i am trying to login using login funcion.

INFO: Response - 
Exception in thread "main" com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.exception.UnauthorizedAccessException: Unauthorized
    at com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.RestUtil.login(RestUtil.java:281)
    at com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.VcloudClient.login(VcloudClient.java:335)
    at ComposevApp.main(ComposevApp.java:271)

i am passing exact username and password that i used for login in web console still i am getting the above error.

Please help me on this

Comment: Instead of the "exact username" try `yourusername@yourorganization` - see *Logging In and Getting an Organization List* at http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vcd_55_sdk_java_dg.pdf

Comment: i am passing below argument 
https://p4v15-vcd.vchs.vmware.com/  vchs-cert7@M263083285-4455  vCA706m! M263083285-4455 M263083285-4455 vapptemplatename

my exact user name is vchs-cert7@vmware.com 
my organization name is M263083285-4455 
then what should be my username to login into vmware using sdk. i tried every possible combination

Answer (score 0):

I have used vCloud API Java SDK to query vCloud resources successfully by using traditional username/passoword credential.

For example,

(1) if we use empty arguments to query all VMs, we will get the result below:

java QueryAllVMs vCloudURL user@organization password

CertificateKeyStorePath[optional] CertificateKeyStorePassword[optional]

java QueryAllVMs https://vcloud user@System password

java QueryAllVMs https://vcloud user@System password certificatekeystorepath certificatekeystorepassword

(2) if we submit the correct arguments to query all VMs, we will get the result below:

Query All VM's

VMName : Vm1 VMMoref : vm-337

VMName : Vm2 VMMoref : vm-334

VMName : Vm3 VMMoref : vm-336

VMName : Vm4 VMMoref : vm-328

An example of Query arguments with administrator login credential is:

java QueryAllVMs https://vcloud.vmwareprovider.com administrator@system administrator-password1234

https://vcloud.vmwareprovider.com/cloud/ 
will displays the Administrator login GUI of vCloud Director

We can use administrator login credential (i.e., "administrator" and "administrator-password1234") to log in to 
https://vcloud.vmwareprovider.com/cloud/